# How to use mysql live update on a mysql table between localhost and remote server?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have mysql table created/modifying in localhost, and I need to update those in my remote database.

I have gone through lot of post regarding this scenario and I found out that I need to use mysql replication for overcome this situation.I went through some posts about mysql replication but I couldn't understand how would I do this.

Is this the method I need to use? If yes, please mention the simplest way on how to use this method?

> NOTE:- my localhost contains Inventory stock system that I have
>   coded.I just need to link or maintain the finish good list on my
>   remote server as product list. Any update of finish good must update in
>   remote server,this is what I need to do.

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Check this : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234814/how-to-update-data-from-localhost-mysql-server-to-remote-mysql-server)

That is Below one :

Can't you use [Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234814/how-to-update-data-from-localhost-mysql-server-to-remote-mysql-server)?

> 22.5.5:  Is it possible for a trigger to update tables on a remote server? 
>   Yes. A table on a remote server could
>   be updated using the FEDERATED storage
>   engine.

From : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-22-5-1-5

I wouldn't recommend this because you will be consuming bandwidth for every small change you do. You can try a scheduled job instead.